# JPA Specification limit 1

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, criteria-api

How to limit the query to return the first one within specification (like limit 1 in sql)

```
public static Specification<Foo> one() {
    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
    ???
  }
}
```

I haven't found anything present as in TypedQuery method : setMaxResults

Answer (score 1):

If you are using spring-data-jpa.

You can use `@Query` in your JpaRepository.

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "SELECT * FROM Foo f WHERE f.name = :name LIMIT 1")
Foo getFoo(@Param("name") String name);
```

Or you can use `EntityManager` `createQuery()` and `setMaxResult()` from there.

Comment: Thank you, but I want to use Specification as it is a bit more complex than my Foo example :-)

Comment: Please check the edited answer about EntityManager.

Comment: Yes, it is a possibility (dunno if it is the only option in fact), but...I'm a bit reluctant to add the entityManager to the class...but I keep that in mind.